# How to detect float precisions in WebGL?

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, glsl, webgl

`lowp`, `mediump` and `highp` means not the same precision on each device. How is it possible to detect the actual values of them (the bit length of the float at each precision)?

I mean:

```
- lowp:   16bit float
- mediump 32bit float
- highp   64bit float (double)
```

Comment: Why would you need it?

Comment: I'm working on a fractal renderer, and I have to know, how deep I can zoom in, before I lost precision

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can call `gl.getShaderPrecisionFormat(shaderType, precisionType)`

`shaderType` is either `gl.VERTEX_SHADER` or `gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER`.

`precisionType` is one of `gl.LOW_FLOAT`, `gl.GL_MEDIUM_FLOAT`, `gl.HIGH_FLOAT`, `gl.LOW_INT`, `gl.MEDIUM_INT`, `gl.GL_HIGH_INT`.

It returns an object that looks like this

```
{
    rangeMin,  // log 2 of the minimum representable magnitude
    rangeMax,  // log 2 of the maximum representable magnitude
    precision, // log 2 of the precision
};
```

> If a high precision floating-point format is not supported for fragment shaders, calling gl.getShaderPrecisionFormat with arguments gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER and gl.HIGH_FLOAT will return 0 for both range and precision.

[docs are here](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/#5.14.9) which link to the OpenGL ES 2.0 docs [here](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetShaderPrecisionFormat.xml)